# RSA_public_encrypt and struct openssl

Tags: c, unix, struct, openssl

How could be the best way to fill a struct consisting only in char array with encrypted text with RSA?
Now my struct is like this:

```
typedef struct s {
    char a[20];
    char b[10];
    char c[1024];
}pack;
```

i've think to change the struct definition like this

```
    typedef struct s {
        char *a;
        char *b;
        char *c;
    }pack;
```

then call

```
RSA_public_encrypt
```

save the encrypted string in a temporary variable, 
use the return value of RSA_public_encrypt to malloc the field of struct, 
and only now copy the string from temporary to struct field.
There's another simple way to do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. Why do you need three character buffers? All you need is a character buffer to store the encrypted output from RSA_public_encrypto. Also, please note that RSA_public_encrypt doesn't return strings (they are not null terminated). So, you should handle them like a buffer and not like a string.

Comment: i need three character buffer because i'm working on client/server application, and this is the struct of exchanged data.